# JavaScript with show and hide using toggle or IF statements on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just struggling with this problem - for days now. 
Perhaps I over-complicated a simple piece of code.. but anyway I need to show some divs when a button is clicked, the first set of code would only trigger on the second click (because I used VAR.style.display) so I tried toggle but now it isn't working at all... Please enlighten me what am I doing wrong?

In the first version of code I had the `display: none;` set on the service menu (servicesMORE), and was just trying to change it when the button (serviceclick) is clicked.

```
//serviceclick button opens menus
$(".serviceclick").click(function(){

   var service = document.getElementById("servicesMORE");
   var serviceclick = document.getElementById("scroll_to_explore2");

//more than 768 and services hidden
   if(service.style.display === "none" && document.documentElement.clientWidth > 768){
       document.getElementById("services").style.height = "1600px";
       service.style.display = "block";
       serviceclick.style.display = "none";
   }
//less than 400 and services hidden
    else if(service.style.display === "none" && document.documentElement.clientWidth < 400){
       document.getElementById("services").style.height = "1100px";
       service.style.display = "block";
       serviceclick.style.display = "none";
   }
//less than 400 and services shown
    else if(service.style.display === "block" && document.documentElement.clientWidth < 400){
       document.getElementById("services").style.height = "400px";
       service.style.display = "none";
        serviceclick.style.display = "block";
   }
//less than 768 and services hidden
    else if(service.style.display === "none" && document.documentElement.clientWidth < 768){
       document.getElementById("services").style.height = "1300px";
       service.style.display = "block";
       serviceclick.style.display = "none";
   }
//less than 768 and services shown
    else if(service.style.display === "block" && document.documentElement.clientWidth < 768){
       document.getElementById("services").style.height = "600px";
       service.style.display = "none";
        serviceclick.style.display = "block";
   }
//this covers more than 768 and is the default behavior - services hidden
   else{
       document.getElementById("services").style.height = "800px";
       service.style.display = "none";
       serviceclick.style.display = "block";
   }

});
```

Then in the latest code, I tried the toggle method but I am pretty sure I am missusing it somehow which is why it does nothing when button is clicked.

For this, I took removed the CSS property `display: none;` from the services menus, assigned the `.hiddenSER` class to the services menus and added this to CSS:

```
.hiddenSER {
    display: none;
}

.showSER{
    display: block;
}
```

And the JS for the second version:

```
$(".serviceclick").click(function(){

   var service = document.getElementById("servicesMORE");
   var serviceclick = document.getElementById("scroll_to_explore2");

   $('#servicesMORE').toggleClass('showSER');


});
```

I would appreciate your expertise, since I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: It may help if we can see your html.
One way to hide/show a div onclick is `myButton.addEventListner("click", function(){ if(myDiv.style.display == "block"){ myDiv.style.display = "none"; } else { myDiv.style.display = "block"; } });`

Comment: @cat do i have to define "myButton" beforehand as well as "myDiv" is that done using variable? Sorry for a stupid question

Comment: Yep, myButton is a javascript variable holding a reference to an html element. You can select an element from the DOM (ie the browser's internal representation of the page) with `document.getElementById("theIdOfYourDesiredElement")`. You already have examples of this in your code (assigned to the variables `service` and `serviceclick`). MDN is a great site to learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For show or hide just create simple class with `display:none;` property
and toggle it using jquery like below.

```
$('#servicesMORE').toggleClass('hiddenSER ');
```

If you want to hide on load time just assign `hiddenSER` class to the tag.

**Edit: Register function on Click**

```
$(".serviceclick").click(function(){

    $('#servicesMORE').toggleClass('hiddenSER ');

});
```

Comment: Yes but how do I trigger the event - with click?

Comment: you need to write this piece of code in your js file (used within this page) and its all set